# How can I exclude certain URLs in Solr / Lucene

Tags: lucene, solr

I have setup new instance of Solr indexing on a website. I want Solr NOT to index certain URL patterns. Is there any way of mentioning such exclude-pattern?

Regards,
Paras

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done in the program, index only if the pattern does not match the exclude pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the filtering in Solr using an [UpdateRequestProcessor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor). In that UpdateRequestProcessor, you could decide whether or not to index the document if it matches or not your regex.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a crawler going about and collecting data?  I would lean towards doing that logic in the crawler.  Solr is more of respository, and I don't think is the best place to put lots of indexing logic in.

Eric